# Windows File Explorer opens when exiting full screen mode

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, fullscreen

Every time I close a Full screen application (like a Remote Desktop terminal, a game, a video on Youtube or just hit F11 twice on Google Chrome), a Windows Explorer window pops up.

It's a very weird Behavior for sure. It never happened before. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I found the solution: I just updated the GPU driver.

My GPU is an AMD R9 280X. The driver version 20.5.1 fixed the problem.

Yeah, pretty awkward solution.